# Execute package via dtexec on remote computer

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've problem with authentication configuration for running SSIS on remote machine.
I've developed some packages. All works fine in debug mode (visual studio).
When Deployed they works only if executed into an agent job (with the sqlserver agent job as executor).

I need to execute the package via dtexec, but with my user I follow into "this logon mode is unavailable for this user" exception. I also tried to use the sqlserver service account to run the dtexec command. This didn't work too, but the error was on authentication between untrusted domain.
I found on the db server that the SSIS service run with a NT Authority local user. This may be the problem? Run the service with a domain account? This may explain me the problem I faced running dtexec on remote machine with sqlserver service account and why It works only with sql agent account.

Running with my user dtexec on remote machine how I must set the authorization to logon? My windows account is also administrator on dbserver and sysdba on sqlserver.

Answer (score 0):

> this logon mode is unavailable for this user

Means that your user doesn't have rights to log on in the "logon mode" required.  I'm not sure if it needs "Log on as a Service" or "Log on as a batch job".  These are configured in [User Rights Assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-rights-assignment)

Generally see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver16

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/

Comment: Running as job agent all works fine. I'll try to check the user's rights. I also found a discussion about kerberos and two level federation. I'll try these tips and I'let you know if they solved my problem